# Get only alphanumeric part of regex string

Tags: php, regex

Let's say I can have strings like these:

```
^(www.|)mysite1.com$
^(.*)mysite2.com(.*)$
^(www\.|)mysite3\.com$
```

How do I get only the **mysite1**, **mysite2** or **mysite3** part of such strings. I tried set the non-alphanumeric parts to empty string using:

```
preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/", '', $mystring);
```

But that returns me

```
mysite1com
mysite2com
mysite3com
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: looks like that would return the www as well. It doesn't?

Comment: ^^^ what @IncredibleHat said.  You'll earn points and others will be encouraged to help you.

Comment: What about `(?<=\))\w+`

Comment: [You may use this regex in php: `^\^\([^)]*\)\K[\w-]+`](https://regex101.com/r/cFnOok/1(

Comment: or you may want to use `\w{4,}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you might do is use [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) instead of [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) and use for example this regex:

[`\^\([^)]+\)\K[A-Za-z0-9]+`](https://regex101.com/r/SjIOgw/1/)

**That would match**

```
\^           # Match ^
\(           # Match (
[^)]+        # Match not ) one or more times
\)           # Match )
\K           # Reset the starting point of the reported match
[A-Za-z0-9]+ # Match one or more upper/lowercase character or digit
```

For example:

```
preg_match("/\^\([^)]+\)\K[A-Za-z0-9]+/", "^(www.|)mysite1.com$", $matches);
echo $matches[0];
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/VFqtC)

With preg_replace an approach could be to use 3 capturing groups where the value you want to keep is in the second group.
In the replacement, you would use `$2`:

[`(\^\([^)]+\))([A-Za-z0-9]+)(.*)`](https://regex101.com/r/Hj053Y/1)

```
preg_replace("/(\^\([^)]+\))([A-Za-z0-9]+)(.*)/", '$2', $mystring);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/43n7n)

Comment: @user765368 If this answer solves your issue, please award the green tick.  If there is still something that isn't quite right, please notify Thefourthbird and I recommend updating your question as well.